# fixture switch wiring

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

I (stupidly) interpreted from the word-less IKEA light fixture instructions that the fixtures (2) had their own on/off switch.  As a result, I wired power to 2 fixture boxes, wired up the fixtures, turned the power on, and realized the fixtures actually have their own dimmer switch, but not on/off.  I was stuck with lights that were always on!

Question: is this drawing the correct way to fix my issue - for both lights to be controlled by 1 switch?

Much appreciated!!!

[image: drawing]

Answer (score 1):

You're *almost* there!  Simply run a /3 cable instead of the /2 to the switch; this lets you run the switched hot using the cable's *red* wire, freeing up its white to be connected to neutral at the fixture end and capped off at the switch end.  This is required for future use as per NEC 404.2(C):

> **(C) Switches Controlling Lighting Loads.** The grounded
>   circuit conductor for the controlled lighting circuit shall be
>   provided at the location where switches control lighting
>   loads that are supplied by a grounded general-purpose
>   branch circuit for other than the following:
>
> (1) Where conductors enter the box enclosing the switch
>   through a raceway, provided that the raceway is large
>   enough for all contained conductors, including a
>   grounded conductor
>
> (2) Where the box enclosing the switch is accessible for
>   the installation of an additional or replacement cable
>   without removing finish materials
>
> (3) Where snap switches with integral enclosures comply
>   with 300.15(E)
>
> (4) Where a switch does not serve a habitable room or
>   bathroom
>
> (5) Where multiple switch locations control the same lighting load such that the entire floor area of the room or space is visible from the single or combined switch locations
>
> (6) Where lighting in the area is controlled by automatic
>   means
>
> (7) Where a switch controls a receptacle load
>
> Informational Note: The provision for a (future) grounded
>   conductor is to complete a circuit path for electronic lighting control devices.

Comment: By the way when the Code says "ground***ed*** [circuit] conductor", it means "neutral".  It does not mean ground.   It means literally the conductor (active wire in the circuit, a safety ground is not a conductor in this meaning) whose voltage is quite near ground because it is bonded to the building's ground rods back in the main panel. Long winded way of saying neutral.  I was hoping with his easy attic access, OP could snake under the 404.2C2 exception, or the existing switch loop would be grandfathered.

Comment: Thanks Harper & ThreePhaseEel for the quick and helpful response!  To make sure I got it: I will use a 14/3 for the switch leg.  Black from switch ties to black for fixtures.  Red from switch ties to Black from source.  White from Switch ties to all whites in j-box.  And ground from switch ties to all grounds in j-box.  Correct?  Thanks!

Comment: @matt -- what you suggest will work just fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  What makes this "full of win" is the star topology, with each point coming together in a central junction box.  That means you can use /2 cable for everything, and it all becomes rather easy!

Comment: This setup is almost there, actually -- it doesn't meet the 404.2(C) requirement for a neutral in the switch box

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel **Ack!! You're right!!**  So close, too.